# Converting gettimeofday() microsecond to seconds

Tags: android

In Android framework code, there's a piece of code that computes the current time in micro seconds as below. Would anyoone know why the factor 1000000ll and not 1000000?

```
static int64_t getNowUs() {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

    return (int64_t)tv.tv_usec + tv.tv_sec * 1000000ll;
}
```

Comment: this is from here http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/rtsp/ARTPAssembler.cpp

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that may just be a 64-bit integer-suffix, like C++.

Answer (score 0):

1000000ll is 1000000  long long, l at the end of an Integer means long, if you look here http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/ex/variablespeed/jni/integral_types.h it has

```
typedef long long int64;  // NOLINT
```

http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/rtsp/ARTPAssembler.cpp